# XTEA encryption in PHP and decryption in C

Tags: php, c++, c, encryption, arduino

I'm trying to establish communication between a website and an Arduino. I need to authenticate all the messages from my website to the Arduino, so I have found that the less time expensive way is using [XTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) cryptography.

My PHP code for the website is:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_XTEA, 'qwertyuiasdfghjk', 'asdfasdf', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

where "qwertyuiasdfghjk" is a 128 bits key and "asdfasdf" is a 64 bits message.

On the Arduino side I'm using:

```
void _xtea_dec(void* dest, const void* v, const void* k)
{
    uint8_t i;
    uint32_t v0=((uint32_t*)v)[0], v1=((uint32_t*)v)[1];
    uint32_t sum=0xC6EF3720, delta=0x9E3779B9;
    for(i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
        v1 -= ((v0 << 4 ^ v0 >> 5) + v0) ^ (sum + ((uint32_t*)k)[sum>>11 & 3]);
        sum -= delta;
        v0 -= ((v1 << 4 ^ v1 >> 5) + v1) ^ (sum + ((uint32_t*)k)[sum & 3]);
    }
    ((uint32_t*)dest)[0]=v0; ((uint32_t*)dest)[1]=v1;
}
```

where the parameters are:

```
char dest[9]; //Destination
char v[9]; //Encrypted message
char k[17]; //Key
```

but my decrypted message is far away from the original message... It still having 64 bits, but it is totally different...

What should I do?

(This is the first time that I ask a question here, usually I all my questions are solved somewhere in Stack Overflow...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your cipher keys are different. Make sure they are the same in both ends.

C:

```
  // "annoying monkey"
  uint32_t key[4] = {0x6f6e6e61, 0x676e6979, 0x6e6f6d20, 0x0079656b };
```

PHP:

```
 mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_XTEA, 'annoying monkey', 'data', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, the XTEA specification did not provide test vectors and your code does not seem to care about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Most probably it is a matter of key or data assumed/being in the wrong endian. Look at the implementation of `mcrypt_encrypt` function in the PHP source.

Comment: thanks, I got your point. I will try what you said! thanks. Unfortunately I cant give you any point (the system says me that I have not enough points).