# Generate key for encryption in PHP which can be placed directly in C++ code for decryption

Tags: php, c++, encryption

I am trying to build an application which generates an encryption key which is then placed directly in the code of a C++ application to decrypt it.

I am confused as to how a string in PHP is converted to the format used in C++.

As an example, have a look at this question here:
[XTEA encryption in PHP and decryption in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132153/xtea-encryption-in-php-and-decryption-in-c/10136328)

How did the answer by *dschulz* get the string

```
annoying monkey
```

to

```
uint32_t key[4] = {0x6f6e6e61, 0x676e6979, 0x6e6f6d20, 0x0079656b };
```

And how can this be done in PHP, so it prints that line in that format?

I've tried converting strings to hex and affixing 0x but it just doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

That is simply the ascii value of the text in hex & [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) format:

```
     a  n  n  o    y  i  n  g       m  o  n    k  e  y  
Hex: 61 6e 6e 6f   79 69 6e 67   20 6d 6f 6e   6b 65 79 00 
       \     /       \     /       \     /       \     / 
       reverse       reverse       reverse       reverse    
       /     \       /     \       /     \       /     \
     {0x6f6e6e61,   0x676e6979,   0x6e6f6d20,   0x0079656b };
```

Comment: Great visual representation! have my +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert the string:

```
<?php
$var = "annoying monkey";
$hex = '';
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($var); $i++){
    $ord     = ord($var[$i]);
    $hexCode = dechex($ord);
    $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
}
echo $hex; // 616e6e6f79696e67206d6f6e6b6579
```

After this, you only need to split the string into chunks of 8 and reverse the groups of 2 digits (each of the 4 letters)

```
$parts = str_split($hex,8);
foreach($parts as $key=>$value){
    // pad right to make last group 8 chars long, even if it's shorter
    $parts[$key] = str_pad($value, 8, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT); 
    // split it into groups of 2 digits - each letter
    $innerParts  = str_split($parts[$key],2);
    // reverse the order
    $innerParts  = array_reverse($innerParts);
    // join and start with '0x'
    $parts[$key] = "0x".implode('',$innerParts);
}
print_r($parts); 
//Array
//(
//    [0] => 0x6f6e6e61
//    [1] => 0x676e6979
//    [2] => 0x6e6f6d20
//    [3] => 0x0079656b
//)
```

You can see it here:

https://3v4l.org/AVObB

To get your final string,

```
$string = 'uint32_t key['.count($parts).'] = {'. implode(',', $parts). '};';
echo $string;
// uint32_t key[4] = {0x6f6e6e61,0x676e6979,0x6e6f6d20,0x0079656b};
```

Answer (score 0):

kindof tricky, given that in your raw php string, they're both "big endian bit order AND big endian byte order", here's one way to convert them (this approach use more cpu than required though, there's definitely a faster way than this)

```php
<?php
// the raw key binary, big endian bit order, big endian byte order:
$key_bit_order_big_byte_order_big = "annoying_monkey";
//<pad>
// pad it to 32bits/4 bytes (uint32_t)
$pad_bytes = strlen($key_bit_order_big_byte_order_big) % 4;
if($pad_bytes > 0){
    $pad_bytes = 4 - $pad_bytes;
    assert($pad_bytes > 0);
    $key_bit_order_big_byte_order_big .= str_repeat("\x00", $pad_bytes);
}
//</pad>

// convert from "big endian bit order, big endian byte order" to 
// "little endian bit order, big endian byte order":
$key_bit_order_little_byte_order_big = strrev($key_bit_order_big_byte_order_big);
// convert from "little endian bit order, big endian byte order" to 
// "little endian bit order, little endian byte order": 
$key_bit_order_little_byte_order_little = implode("", array_reverse(str_split($key_bit_order_little_byte_order_big, 4), false));

// now to c++-ify it: 
$key_chunks_little_endian = str_split($key_bit_order_little_byte_order_little, 4);
foreach($key_chunks_little_endian as &$chunk){
    $chunk = "0x".bin2hex($chunk);
}
unset($chunk);
echo "uint32_t key[".count($key_chunks_little_endian)."] = {".implode(", ", $key_chunks_little_endian)."};";
```

outputs:

```
uint32_t key[4] = {0x6f6e6e61, 0x676e6979, 0x6e6f6d5f, 0x0079656b};
```